# Qt Quick drop down menus crash program

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

Recently I installed Qt 5.2. and after playing around I discovered that most visual components in Qt Quick who have some sort of drop down functionality (e.g combo boxes, menu bar items) crash the program when I choose something from them. same thing applied for my projects that worked file in 5.1. I googled the problem but nothing useful came up. 
I'm running it on a ubuntu 12.04 64bit.  and this is a sample code that crashes by receiving SIGSEGV when I use the "File" item in the menu bar and the same thing happens when the combo box is used.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    ComboBox {
        id: combo
        model: [1, 2, 3]
    }

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

## Update:

this is the stack 

`0   ??          0x21

1   QOpenGLContext::makeCurrent(QSurface*)  /home/abo0ody/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5       0x7ffff6482f4b

2   ??  /home/abo0ody/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5     0x7ffff79a2dfc

3   ??  /home/abo0ody/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5     0x7ffff79a30da

4   ??  /home/abo0ody/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5     0x7ffff79a392e

5   ??  /home/abo0ody/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5     0x7ffff79a3a92

6   ??  /home/abo0ody/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5      0x7ffff5d3bf38

7   start_thread    pthread_create.c    308 0x7ffff4959e9a

8   clone   clone.S 112 0x7ffff54bc3fd

9   ??`

the kit that I'm running it with was auto detected and it's version name is "Qt 5.2.0 GCC 64bit" with the qmake location "/home/UserName/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake". 
I run it normally by pressing the run button. 
g++ version is "g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04) 4.8.1".

## Update:

Here is a simple main.cpp that can load the QML file by default or take an argument from the command line that specifies the path to a QML file to load, As Laszlo Papp suggested. But it still reproduces the same error for me.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickWindow>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString pathToMainQML = "qml/testdrop/main.qml"; // if no command line argument is specified this qml file will be used
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : pathToMainQML);
    QObject *topLevel = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(topLevel);
    window->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you run this qml code?

Comment: Where exactly does it crash? Did you try with a debugger?

Comment: Can you try it out with a simple main.cpp that loads your qml, and from the command line?

Comment: I updated the info in the post to answer the question of @LaszloPapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Qt 5.2 and I have already reported it. A work around could be to set an environment variable "QSG_RENDER_LOOP=basic" in your system environment. For more details see [QTBUG-35989](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-35989) and [qt forum discussion](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/35888/)